# Saving the arguments in different variables passed to a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to save two command line arguments in  two different variables and rest all in third variable.
I am using following code

```
while [ $# -ge 2 ] ; do
  DirFrom=$1
  Old_Ver=`basename $1`
  shift
  DirTo=$1
  shift
  pdct_code=$@
  shift
done
```

This code is failing if I send more than three arguments . Please suggest how  can I save 3rd 4th and so on variable in pdct_code variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not entering the loop when you have more than two arguments. You can bump the argument limit like so:

```
while [ $# -ge 3 ]; do
    :
done
```

or better yet just parse your arguments without looping at all. For example:

```
DirFrom="$1"
Old_Ver=`basename "$1"`
DirTo="$2"
pdct_code="$*"
```

Answer (score 0):

No loop or `shift`ing is needed. Note that `pdct_code` may need to be an array, to preserve the exact arguments passed to your script.

```
if [ $# -ge 2 ]; then
    DirFrom=$1
    Old_Ver=$(basename "$1")
    DirTo=$2
    pdct_code="${@:3}"
    # pdct_code=( "${@:3}" )
done
```